# How to initialize a member array in a template

Tags: c++, templates, constants, allocation

I would like to have an array which has a length that depends on the parameter of my template, but I keep getting the "expected constant expression" error.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    FIRST,
    OTHER
};

template<MyEnum e> 
struct MyTemplate
{
    static const int arrSize;
    int myArr[arrSize];            // error C2057: expected constant expression
    // int myArr[e == FIRST ? 4 : 10]; // works, but isn't very readable...
};

template<>
const int MyTemplate<FIRST>::arrSize = 4;

template<>
const int MyTemplate<OTHER>::arrSize = 10;
```

The compiler I must use does not support `constexpr`, or any other C++ 11 features, and I also cannot pass the array size as a template parameter.

edit: I also must not use `new`.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this the compiler must know `arrSize` when you're declaring `int myArr[arrSize]`

Comment: imo, `e == FIRST ? 4 : 10` is more readable than introducing template specializations... the more times you use the `template` keyword, the less readable your code is

Comment: @Brian It is for this example, but I have 10+ of possibilities in the real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases like this, I'll add a function `get_array_size<e>()`.  Since you say you don't have constexpr, there's still decent possibilities:

```
//I call this a pseudo-template-function, but there's probably better names
template<MyEnum> struct GetArraySize; //compiler error for default
template<> struct GetArraySize<FIRST> {static const int value=4;};
template<> struct GetArraySize<OTHER> {static const int value=10;};

template<MyEnum e> 
struct MyTemplate
{
    static const int arrSize = GetArraySize<e>::value;
    int myArr[arrSize];
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f03a5fa94a038892

Comment: I haven't yet figured out how to get this _inside_ of `MyTemplate` though.

Answer (score 1):

Are we reinventing the wheel here ? **Enums are compile time constants**. Just do this :

```
enum MyEnum
{
    FIRST = 4,
    OTHER = 10
};

template<MyEnum e> 
struct MyTemplate
{
    int myArr[e];      
};
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50bad7f165804e35)

Comment: I cannot, because the enum has some other value that is used somewhere else.

Comment: Still, not a bad answer to have on the page

Comment: then take that value and add N where N is the number of the result you want minus the value

Comment: The function that would map the enum values to the array size I want is not linear!

Comment: @Phil Is it exponential ? Haha just joking man, you 're better aware of the details, I was just trying to help.